# Problem while installing Ubuntu 16.04 in freeDOS (MSI)

Tags: boot, usb

I just got MSI (GL738R3) with FreeDOS. I am booting from USB to install Ubuntu 16.04 (amd64 version). I am using 16.04 as it is compatible with ROS kinetic. The problem is that after booting from USB, it asks different options like try Ubuntu, install Ubuntu etc.

I select install Ubuntu and then after seeing a command prompt for second the the systems hangs at this point.I have tried it many times but it sticks every time. kindly tell me what can be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to "Try ubuntu" instead of install? If yes, what is the result?

Comment: yes with try ubuntu as well the computer hangs up after it in a similar way

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past. Sometimes reinstalling the USB key is enough. Sometimes it's better to change the USB key. Can you handle one of these solutions?

Comment: i tried both these options. result is exactly the same

Comment: So I don't really know more to try :/ sorry. Hopefully someone will give some better ideas... Or have you tried to look on Ask Ubuntu for similar issues?

Comment: yes i have. turning acpi off worked fro me for installing. but after installing the system when the system restarts it was stuck again

Comment: Have you tried to boot again with ACPI=off since you installed your system?

Comment: Yes i boot again through acpi off. It starts the installation process but shows the previous installed system. In the end after the process the system asks for restart and it gets stuck again

Comment: When you say that it "shows the previous installed system", do you mean FreeDOS or your previous attempt to install Ubuntu? May I suggest you to boot in a live session, take a screenshot of your hard drive(s) in GParted, and update your post with it? Also, do you know if the command prompt you see when your computer is stuck is the one from Ubuntu or FreeDOS?

Comment: 1.The previous installed system shown is of ubuntu that is installed. 2.the command prompt shown after restarting always enters in FreeDOS.